# Unit test for a method, which calls other methods

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalamock

I have the class `A` with private methods `a` and `b` and public method `c`.

Methods `a` and `b` are covered by tests.

The public method `c` is used with a parameter, so it can call `a` or `b` with `if stmt`

I want test method `c` with `behavior-based test` (test `a` called for some parameter and `b` called for other). I can't figure out how achieve this with `ScalaTest` and `ScalaMock`

Part of the class code

```
  protected final def generate(leftBranch: List[L], leftPoint: L, rightBranch: List[L], rightPoint: L): C = {
    val lEmpty = leftBranch.isEmpty
    val rEmpty = rightBranch.isEmpty
    if (lEmpty && rEmpty) {
      val cc = leafOrdering.compare(leftPoint, rightPoint)
      if (cc < 0) {
        nextOrExpand(leftPoint){ p =>
          if (leafOrdering.compare(p, rightPoint) < 0) {
            usePoint(p)

          } else
            expand(leftPoint)

        }
      }
      else if (cc == 0)
        throw SamePointException()

      else
        throw LowerRestrictionException()

    }
    else if (lEmpty) {
      val cc = leafOrdering.compare(leftPoint, rightBranch.head)
      if (cc < 0)
        nextOrExpand(leftPoint){ p =>
          if (leafOrdering.compare(p, rightBranch.head) <= 0) {
            usePoint(p)

          } else {
            expand(leftPoint)
          }

        }

      else if (cc == 0)
        minimalRestricted(List(leftPoint), startBranchWith, rightBranch.tail, rightPoint)

      else
        throw LowerRestrictionException()

    }
    else if (rEmpty)
      if (leafOrdering.compare(leftBranch.head, rightPoint) < 0)
        next(leftBranch, leftPoint)

      else
        throw LowerRestrictionException()

    else {
      if (leafOrdering.compare(leftBranch.head, rightBranch.head) < 0)
        next(leftBranch, leftPoint)

      else {        
        throw LowerRestrictionException()

      }

    }
  }
```

Methods `nextOrExpand`, `usePoint`, `expand`, `minimalRestricted`, `next` are private and tested. The `generate` method is a public method that needs to be tested.

Comment: What did you try? What's not working?

Comment: Also, this can be considered an anti pattern to test `a` and `b` unless they are very specific. Just test `c`. Unit test doesn't mean you have to test every single method in isolation: it means you test one thing and the granularity of this thing can vary.

Comment: @GaëlJ I have written tests for methods `a` and `b` but I didn't understand how to test the method `c` correctly. In fact, these methods are repeated sections of code in the `c` method, therefore , they are put into separate methods. I tested them to make sure that they work correctly for myself. A search on the Internet for testing options gave two options (If I understood them correctly): 1. testing state (call the method and assert the result) 2. test behavior (call the method and assert the methods are called inside it)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, with `behavior-based test` you want to write your test like the example showed [here](https://www.scalatest.org/at_a_glance/WordSpec)

```
class SetSpec extends AnyWordSpec {

  // Describe a scope for a subject, in this case: "A Set"
  "A Set" can { // All tests within these curly braces are about "A Set"

    // Can describe nested scopes that "narrow" its outer scopes
    "empty" should { // All tests within these curly braces are about "A Set (when empty)"

      "have size 0" in {    // Here, 'it' refers to "A Set (when empty)". The full name
        assert(Set.empty.size == 0) // of this test is: "A Set (when empty) should have size 0"
      }
      "produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked" in { // Define another test
        intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
          Set.empty.head
        }
      }
      "should be empty" ignore { // To ignore a test, change 'it' to 'ignore'...
        assert(Set.empty.isEmpty)
      }
    }

    // Describe a second nested scope that narrows "A Set" in a different way
    "non-empty" should { // All tests within these curly braces are about "A Set (when non-empty)"

      "have the correct size" in { // Here, 'it' refers to "A Set (when non-empty)". This test's full
        assert(Set(1, 2, 3).size == 3)     // name is: "A Set (when non-empty) should have the correct size"
      }
      // Define a pending test by using (pending) for the body
      "return a contained value when head is invoked" is (pending)
      import tagobjects.Slow
      "be non-empty" taggedAs (Slow) in { // Tag a test by placing a tag object after the test name
        assert(Set(1, 2, 3).nonEmpty)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If that's what you want, you would be able to see that you can `mix different traits` to write your tests using different styles. Also based on which one you pick, the output of the test will be different.

scalatest also provide a rich DSL that will let you write your test close to a natural language. You can use [matchers](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers) that offer different methods such as `have`, `be`, `contains`, etc

Comment: I'm new to testing, therefore, I can make mistakes in the approaches to testing. I think if `a` and `b` are tested and `c` has `if (f) a() else b() `, test for `c` will a combining from `a` and `b` tests and will repeat the same tests. So if I can check which method was called, then I will need only two tests for `f == true` and `f == false`

Comment: It would be better if you show some code to see what you did. Test private methods it's not something you should do unless you have a good reason for that. Please edit your post and provide more details